# javascript strange behaviour of jQuery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I ahve a html file, in which I include .js file. This file contains this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button.save").click(function(){
        alert("payment_type_form_");
    });
    PlanTabs.Open("payments");
    $("#payment-types-accordion").lyfAccordion();
});
```

All good works. But .click() doesn't. If I move this code to html `<script></script>` all good nice.
I want to keep javascript code in file, not in html. How can I do it?
Thank you in advance. Sorry for my english)

Comment: What error are you getting in the page when it's an external file?

Comment: It's a stupid suggestion. But sometime JS gets cached. Did you try clearing cache and then testing it? Or may be you are seeing any error in JS console?

Comment: Try to debug by adding such line: `alert($("button.save").length);` inside the `ready` function - what do you see?

Comment: @Nick Craver. No errors.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard. `alert($("button.save").length);` returns 1.

Comment: @Nishant. I always clean cache.

Comment: How are you including the JS file in the HTML page? Let's see some more code.

Comment: How are you including the JS file? Inside <head> ?

Comment: It makes in Zend Framework. `$this->view->headScript()->appendFile('/scripts/commission/plan.js');` It returns `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/commission/plan.js"></script>`

Comment: SEE MY QUESTION. OTHER CODE IN THIS FILE WORKS PRETTY!

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov - do you have a link to the page exhibiting the behavior?

Comment: @Alexander I suspect that "Zend Framework" is the problem - can you put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/commission/plan.js"></script>` directly in the page?

Comment: SEE MY QUESTION. OTHER CODE IN THIS FILE WORKS PRETTY!

Comment: @Alexander.Plutov - Just a tip: your all caps not-helpful responses and downvoting everyone who answers isn't the best way to get a useful answer.

Comment: -10 if I can, But -1 "cause I don't have any reason".toUpperCase()

Comment: @Alexander you make it really hard to help you - have you tried what I suggested in the previous comment? Shouting at everyone will not solve your problem, that's for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure jQuery is included before this script file?  That's where I've encountered these problems.

Answer (score 1):

try putting your script near the bottom of the `</body>` tag